# Form-based authentication with Python

Tags: python, cookies, forms-authentication

I'm trying to use a code read in [Kent's Korner](http://personalpages.tds.net/~kent37/kk/00010.html) for Form-based authentication. At least I'm told the web site I'm trying to read is form-based authenticated.

But I don't seem to be able to get past the login page. The code I'm using is

```
Import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, string

# configure an opener that will handle cookies
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# use the opener to POST to the login form and the protected page
params = urllib.urlencode(dict(username='user', password='stuff'))
f = opener.open('http://www.hammernutrition.com/forums/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=1323', params)
data = f.read()
f.close()
f = opener.open('http://www.hammernutrition.com/forums/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=1323')
data = f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: You probably have to simulate the submit button click.

Comment: Do you know how to simulate the submit button in Python?

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate a web browser in Python without using much too resources with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)
(Debian/Ubuntu package is called `python-mechanize`). It handles both cookies and submitting forms, just the way a web browser would do, one great example is a [Python Dropbox Uploader](https://github.com/jncraton/PythonDropboxUploader/blob/master/src/dbupload/upload.py) script, which you can transform to your needs.